# Eclipse app keeps disappearing, why and how could i fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I've downloaded Eclipse twice already on my mac because the app and every trace of it keeps disappearing every time i turn off my laptop and then turn it on again. The exact same thing has been happening with my mac desktop. Does anyone know why this might be? thanks!

Edit:
i downloaded the macOS version here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-12/r/eclipse-ide-java-developers !

Comment: What exactly did you download (the _Eclipse Installer_ or a specific IDE package)? Please tell the download URL.

Comment: Maybe you have downloaded the portable version. Download the desktop version [eclipse.org/downloads](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). After download check the system if its successfully installed or not.

Comment: What exactly did you do with the `.dmg` file?

Comment: nothing! used it to open eclipse and then dragged eclipse to applications but the dmg file is still there :/

Comment: After you dragged Eclipse from the dmg, did you then Eject the dmg and finally open the Eclipse in Applications?